# Two JQGrid in Dialog Box

Tags: jqgrid

I am use two jqgrid in Dialog Box.
Problem is that in IE Display Only one Grid.
but in Firefox Both grids are display.
So what's problem.
please Help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You will need to post more details, and some code, to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: That look like css problem. I have no problems with displaying multiple jqGrids in single control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is That Script tag is in the Between the Body Tag.
So In IE Script is inside the tag so this type of Problem occurs.